# USB Drive not showing files

Tags: windows, usb, file-permissions

I have 64GB SanDisk pen drive now days its not showing files and folders inside my pen drive but when checking the used space and unused space is showing correctly

How to fix this issue ?

Comment: Can you try to open the  disk management from Run ->diskmgmt.msc and check whether you are able to explore the file and folder list from there

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this,

Open command prompt (Start -> RUN ->Type CMD and hit enter), execute the following line

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d USB_DRIVE_LETTER_HERE:\*.*
```

and hit enter

P.S: Replace `USB_DRIVE_LETTER_HERE` with flash drive letter, For example, if your pen drive's drive letter is `H` then the command line should be

```
attrib -h -r -s /s /d H:\*.*
```

Comment: worked..........worked.........worked ..........thanks man